# Dispose a CryptoStream after it has thrown a CryptographicException

Tags: c#, encryption, stream, resources, aes

I am currently working on a little tool to encrypt files with AES.
To open, read, en/decrypt and finally write and close the data, I am using a method I called FileBusiness:

```
public void FileBusiness(ICryptoTransform transform, string input, string output)
{
    FileStream inStream = new FileStream(input, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    FileStream outStream = new FileStream(output, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(outStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        int data;
        while ((data = inStream.ReadByte()) != -1)
        {
            cryptoStream.WriteByte((byte)data);
        }
        try
        {
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        }
        catch (CryptographicException)
        {
            //Exception handling goes here...
        }
        finally
        {
            inStream.Close();
            outStream.Close();
        }
    } // <---- Exception is thrown here, when using disposes the cryptoStream
}
```

As far as I got this right, almost always when the user enters a wrong decryption key, `FlushFinalBlock()` will throw a CryptographicException.
So, if no Exception was  thrown, the cryptoStream Disposes automatically, thanks to the using block.
But if it tries to dispose after an exception was thrown, I get another CryptographicException ("padding is invalid and cannot be removed"). I tried calling `Dispose()`, `Close()` and `Clear()` but nothing works.
Am I just supposed to leave it open? I mean, just remove the using block and call `Close()` just after `FlushFinalBlock()`?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Oh and apart from decrypting with the wrong key, everything works just fine, but I surely want to handle wrong keys the right way though...